# Xpath extractor

Tags: xpath, jmeter

Can someone help me with this:
I am using xpath extractor of jmeter to retrieve sessionId value from the below response.

I need the value of the sessionId to be stored in some file, so that i can use that value in succeeding calls..My basic response is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:createUserResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.musicthp.com" 
                        isNewUser="false"
                        profileId="32109" 
                        sessionId="ryIlb+E5yj7FReA2w96uag=="
                        success="true">
 <duration>316</duration>
</ns2:createUserResponse>`
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the results in a future call, you simply need to use the "Reference Name" as a variable.

If you configure the [Xpath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) reference name as `sessionID`, subsequent calls would use `${sessionID}`

Comment: I think user is asking for the xpath expression

Comment: This answer is for second question.